# MVC 3 CRUD for Derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, crud, derived-types

Folks I need help. I am an MVC newbie..

I am getting this error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List'1[BaseClass]`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[DerivedClass]`.

And these are 2 of my Actions

```
namespace Namespace.Controllers
{ 
    public class DerivedController : Controller
    {
        private Context db = new Context();
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var baseClass= db.BaseClass.Include(s => s.Arrea);
        return View(BaseClass.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Derived/Details/5

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Derived derived = db.BaseClass.OfType<Derived>().Single(c => c.SDSID==id);
        return View(derived);
    }
```

I am using EF codefirst with TPT inheritance. Things work up to this point including the base class.
What am I doing wrong? I have been searching on this for 2 days now. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which action is getting the error?

Comment: Both of these actions gives the error

Comment: Can you post the contents of your 2 Views too?  Maybe just the first 5 lines of each if they're quite big.

Comment: @model IEnumerable<Base>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            star
        </th>
        <th> For the index action

Comment: And for the detail Action @model Models.base

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Sleep</legend>

    <div class="display-label">star</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.star)
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

Your view is probably strongly typed, and you're passing the wrong thing to it.

The first line in your view should be something like (if you're using razor)...

```
@model IEnumerable<DerivedClass>
```

Change that to...

```
@model IEnumerable<BaseClass>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it seems it is on the right direction but the new error is like : 'Models.Base' does not contain a definition for 'star' and no extension method 'star' accepting....  Star is a property on the derived class.

Comment: It might be that you have referenced 'star' in your view and it should be 'Star' (with a capital 'S'), public properties are usually capitalised?

Comment: This answer moves in the other direction (change the View to use the BaseClass). You can still typecast to get derived properties.

Comment: @ Adrian, No because these views were generated(Scafold?) I did not type in the 'star' so it referenced correctly.